# neo4j cypher: How to find out if a node is in a collection of relationships?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have this MATCH query for a path:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
```

Now I Would like to match only those paths which do not contain a certain node in a "subpath", e.g. the good paths should not go from `(a)` to `(b)` going over `(avoid1)`. I tried:

```
MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( (a)-[:CF*]->(avoid1)-[:CF*]->(b) )
```

which returned no paths. I guess this is because it is just a check if there is a relation from `(a)` to `(avoid1)` and from `(avoid1)` to `(b)` - which is the case. I then tried

```
MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
WHERE NOT ( (avoid1) IN nodes(sp1) )
```

This did not work either because `sp1` is a `Collection<Relationship>` and not a path. Consequently I got the error:

> Type mismatch: expected Path but was `Collection<Relationship>`

How can I check if a node is in a collection of relations?

Or maybe, is there a smarter way to achieve what I want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you do not want `avoid1` to be anywhere in the path, you can simply use this (query fragment):

```
MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
WHERE NOT avoid1 IN NODES(p)
```

[EDITED]

If you only want to avoid `avoid1` between `a` and `b`, you can do this:

```
MATCH p1=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)
WHERE NOT avoid1 IN NODES(p1)
MATCH p2=(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
```

Finally, if you want to get the full path from `a` to `d` as a single path, you can do the following.

```
MATCH p=(a)-[sp1:CF*]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)
WHERE avoid1 <> a AND NONE(x IN sp1 WHERE avoid1 = ENDNODE(x))
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not the case. `avoid1` may be in the path but not in between `a` and `b`. I guess this is what makes it so complicated :- (

Comment: And how do I return the "merged" or concatenated path(s)? I would like to return the entire (set of) good path(s), not two (sets of) path(s).

Comment: OK, try the new query fragment at the bottom of my updated answer.

Comment: Does not work yet, it returns paths including avoid1 in between a and b. I tried to adapt the last line to `MATCH p2=(a)-[sp1]->(b)-[sp2:CF*]->(c)-[sp3:CF*]->(d)` but got "Type mismatch: sp1 already defined with conflicting type"